# Several different login forms for Spring Security

Tags: java, configuration, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring-security web authentication with spring-mvc with a custom authentication and all is well so far:

My problem is: `/login` loads a view with a fully-featured page, but now I have to provide authentication for iframe/popup format (e.g. for an authenticated bookmarklet), so loading a different view (or with different parameters).

I see two solutions that are not overcomplicated:

1. In my `/login` action, I have a way (unkown to me so far) to retrieve the original request and check it against a set of URLs that use the simpler view, then choose the matching view. => How do I retrieve this original request?
2. I make another login action/form, say `/login/minimal`, which also POSTs to the spring security URL `/j_spring_security_check`, but I need to implement the request storage/retrieval mechanism, so that the original request is performed after successful login. => I see this has something to do with `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`, yet I don't know how to implement it or call it.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you wanting to figure out how to show a different logon page based on the original request or are you asking something different?

Comment: No, you got it right, that was my solution #1 and I asked how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to vary the login page based on the original request string.  Check out [this forum post](http://www.techinfopad.com/spring/100502717-get-original-request-url-from-acegi.html) for accessing the original request url from the session.  It's for an older version, but you should be able to use it to get started.

**Edit** I haven't had a chance to validate this, but it looks like the key changed between Acegi security and Spring Security 3.  It looks like you can access it from session using the constants in the [WebAttributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractProcessingFilter.html) class.  Effectively

```
//request is a HttpServletRequest object
SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest)request.getSession().getAttribute(WebAttributes.SAVED_REQUEST);
String url = savedRequest.getRequestURL();
```

Comment: Worked for me, except that the method initially was `savedRequest.getRedirectURL()`. Now actually the attribute contains a `DefaultSavedRequest` instance, which has a much more practical `getServletPath()` that returns directly `/internal/path` instead of the whole `http://server:port/servlet/internal/path`.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

there is a class `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails`

It contains only the IP of the client and its Session, but

it has a method

```
protected void doPopulateAdditionalInformation(HttpServletRequest request) {}
```

I belive you could enhance this by subclassing and add the request url. -- But check first if the request is the request from the login form, or the "blocked" request.

**Added**

[Chris Thompson posted an other part of the puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672759/several-different-login-forms-for-spring-security/4673939#4673939) to answer your question:
He mentioned that the saved request can be obtained from the session:

```
//request is a HttpServletRequest object
SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest)request.getSession().getAttribute(WebAttributes.SAVED_REQUEST);
String url = savedRequest.getRequestURL();
```

So you can combine this, instead of enhanding the WebAuthenticationDetails you just need to read its already inclueded session.

@see [Chris Thompson answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672759/several-different-login-forms-for-spring-security/4673939#4673939)

Comment: This looks interesting, but how would you know if the request is the blocked one or not?

Comment: @ Abdullah Jibaly: I would read the read the documentation, read the source code or set a break point and test it. -- In this order.